# Why doesn't android studio show type of object or variables

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

If I use Xcode or visual studio all I have to do is hover my mouse (Or alt + hover) to get more information about what the variable is returning or expecting. How can I do the same thing in android studio?

Do I have something toggled off or does android studio not support something like that?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's ctrl + shift + p. You can customize it in File -> Settings -> Keymap -> View -> Expression Type.

Answer (score 18):

One way I've found is simply placing the caret on the variable, and pressing F1. (Works with Flutter).

Alternatively, you can go to `Settings->Editor->Code Editing` and turn on `Show quick documentation on mouse move`.

Comment: I can't believe this is not the default setting

Comment: You made my life so much easier! Thanks a ton :)

Answer (score 8):

In newer versions of android studio it is "Ctrl + Hover"

**EDIT**
On variable declaration line using "Ctrl + Hover" will show *"Usages of variable"*.
On later usage of the variable it will show you its correct data type.

Comment: Doesnt work. Shows the message: "Show usages of variable 'x'"

Comment: @DarkNeuron It will only show that message if you CTRL + Hover over the variable name in variable declaration line because you already know the type of the variable during declaration right ? It will show the data type if you hover on later uses of that variable.